# Setting parent page text box from popup

Tags: javascript

I'm doing the following things:

1) A user clicks on a page and it opens up a pop-up.
2) In the pop-up I try to set a text box in the parent page.

The problem is that the code works in IE, but does not work in Fire Fox. I am testing with FF 3.6.13.   I'm assuming it has to do something with the window.opener.document.getElementById or self.opener.document.getElementById.  I tried both lines they don't work in FF.

```
function passValues(comment_text_box_id)
{
    var checkbox_values = "";
    for(i=0; i<document.form1.elements.length; i++)
    {
        if(document.form1.elements[i].type=="checkbox")
        {
            if(document.form1.elements[i].checked == true)
            {

                if(checkbox_values == ""){

                    checkbox_values = document.form1.elements[i].value;

                }
                else{

                    checkbox_values = checkbox_values + "," + document.form1.elements[i].value;

                }

            }
        }
    }


    //window.opener.document.getElementById(comment_text_box_id).innerText = window.opener.document.getElementById(comment_text_box_id).innerText + checkbox_values;
    self.opener.document.getElementById(comment_text_box_id).innerText = self.opener.document.getElementById(comment_text_box_id).innerText + checkbox_values;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**innerText** is only supported by MSIE. In other browsers create a TextNode containing the given text and insert the TextNode into the target-element. 
Replace the last line with:

```
self.opener.document.getElementById(comment_text_box_id)
 .appendChild(self.opener.document.createTextNode(checkbox_values));
```

(or use innerHTML if the text doesn't contain html-markup)

Comment: Thank you for replying back.  Not completely following you on what you said above. Can you provide an example? Are you saying I should do something like this var x = document.createTextNode(' A new text node has been appended!'). How do I pass the value back to the parent page text box.  Sorry a bit confused.

Comment: I just tried it out.  It works great.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: So I just tested it with FF 3.6.13 and its not working on that browser.  I did work at home with FF 2.x (I don't remember the version).  Any other ideas?

Comment: So you'll have to use your debugger(I'm not a human debugging-service). This works in FF3 the same way like it does in other browsers. http://www.jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/XtDNC/

Comment: Thanks for link with the example, that helps a lot.  Before i read your post, I noticed it was working for me now in the same browser I tested earlier with.  I did reinstall FF (same version), so maybe that fixed it.  Again, thanks for all your help.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Can't seem to see why the following behavior occurs.  So from the pop up page I am adding values to a text box.  Which works fine in IE and FF.  But in FF if I add text to the text box initially and then add values to the texbox from the pop-up.  It does not work. Even if I clear the text box and then try to add values to the textbox from the pop-up again..it still does not work.  Do I need to some type of check before hand, before I call this line "self.opener.document.getElementById(comment_text_box_id)
 .appendChild(self.opener.document.createTextNode(checkbox_values));"?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean with "textbox", what kind of element?

Comment: Got this from the html source code produced by my asp.net page "<textarea name="rptrQuestions$ctl02$txt_comment" rows="2" cols="20" id="rptrQuestions_ctl02_txt_comment" style="height: 100px; width: 500px;">Needs more work.</textarea>".  I use this link to open the pop-up "<a id="rptrQuestions_ctl02_hypAddComment" title="Add Comment" href="javascript:OpenWindow('add_comments.aspx?cmt_id=rptrQuestions_ctl02_txt_comment')"><img title="Add Comment" src="img/btn_comment.gif" style="border-width: 0px;"></a>".

Comment: If it is a form-element, simply modify the value of the element:  `self.opener.document.getElementById(comment_text_box_id).value+=checkbox_values`;

Comment: Very nice it works in FF and IE perfectly.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**
Replace the word ajax with Javascript Framework..  Jquery, Mootools, Etc...

Why not use ajax and create a modal html "popup" that way you remain in the context of the parent page at all times, and you can modify your "parent" page based on what the xmlHttpRequest Object returns.  It stand to benefit using this technique since it will keep your page from being blocked by a popup blocker.

Here is a link I found when I searched for `modal html dialog box`  http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/modal-message/demo-modal-message.html

Comment: Actually the pop-up blocker was blocking my pop-up while I was testing today.  So I might go this route.  Thank you for your input, I appreciate it.